# Django, user uploaded files in media are served correctly but the file doesn't appear to exist

Tags: django

I'm serving django via the built in server.  I'm able to upload files in the backend using FileField and ImageField.  After uploading a link is generated, and the files are available on the link (ie media/uploads/my_file).

However, when i visit the directory 'media/uploads,' there's no files there at all.

In settings.py I have

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Is this normal?  Where can I see where the files actually are?

Thanks,

Comment: If they are served correctly then they exist. You're probably just not looking for them at the right location. Do a search and find out where django uploads them to, then change your settings accordingly

Comment: yes.  i feel silly now.  Thanks,